# Prepending string using replaceAll and regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I can't figure out how to create regular expression using positive lookahead. The idea is to prepend two character string to every two character in a long string. i.e.

```
"090909" => "XX09XX09XX09"
```

This code:

```
String s = "090909";
String ns = s.replaceAll("(?=\\d\\d)", "XX");
```

...doesn't work; the output is `XX0XX9XX0XX9XX09`.  But this code works:

```
String s = "090909";
String ns = s.replaceAll("(?=09)", "XX");
```

I'm confused on how to come up with an expression saying lookahead for every two characters.  Am I missing some boundaries or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
String s = "090909";
String ns = s.replaceAll("(\\d\\d)", "XX$1");
```

The `(` and `)` will create the [capture](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html), and the `$1` accesses the capture.

Comment: +1, but you're missing a `(` in the regex, and the replacement string should be `"XX$1"`, not `"$1XX"`.

Comment: Your code didn't work man. I got new solution s.replaceAll("(?=(\\d\\d)+$)", "XX"), but unfortunately this works only if the length of the string is an even number

Comment: this works!  s.replaceAll("(\\d\\d)", "XX$1"). thanks! Didn't know $1 can be used for string replacement. but thanks a lot

Comment: There was an error in it, as Alan Moore remarked. I think you should still consider using it, since your regex is (probably) less efficient (because of the lookahead assertion)

Comment: race condition with comment posting ;) No problem :)

Comment: Thanks again. Could you please explain the XX$1 part is there any other thins that you can do with string replacement?

Comment: In the first string i use parenthesis around a group. You can do this multiple times if you want. You can then retrieve the groups in the replacement string by inserting $1 $2 $3 etc. I must say I'm a bit surprised you do now positive lookahead assertions, but not backreferences ;)

Comment: Be aware that the solutions yield different results when the string contains an odd number of digits.  Try both with `s="9090909"` to see what I mean.

Comment: Yea string contains odd number of digits produces XX09XX090. I'm expecting output XX09XX09XX0

Comment: Then you definitely don't want the lookahead version.  Change @mark's regex to `"(\\d\\d?)"` instead.